# A callback for a page refresh function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to implement a callback for a page refresh function, check if the page is ready after it is refreshed and then print a message? I'd like to show refresh the page and show a certain message after clicking a button, however, I need to stay within my code in order to know what message to show. Anything similar to the next code would be great:

```
location.reload(function(){
   alert ('done refreshing and document is ready');
});
```

Comment: On page reload, your JS application gets re-initialized and starts all over again, so you cannot have a callback.

Comment: you should just reload/refresh some part of the page using ajax.

Comment: Pass the message (or something indicating which message to show) to your script so it is there on the next load.

Comment: @roasted: That's what I've been trying to do, but then certailn plugins aren't loaded / not affecting the re-loaded fields.

Comment: @passionateCoder - That was a very passionate comment

Comment: @TommyNaidich ya, in this case you need to reload each plugin for new specific elements. But usually the logic is not that hard to implement

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On page reload, your JS application gets re-initialized and starts all over again, so you cannot have a callback.

However, what you can do is add a hash fragment to the URL before reloading.

```
window.location = window.location.href + "#refresh";
window.location.reload();
```

Then, on page load, check if the hash fragment exists. If it does, you'll know you just refreshed the page.

Comment: I'll go with your solution. In that case, though, I have some questions:

After checking whether the page has been reloaded or not, I'd like to print a message. The message consists information which changes according to the reloading reason. Now, what would be the best way to temporarily store data using javascript/JQuery? I'm pretty new to both, thanks.

Comment: You could add the message to the url as well: `example.com#refresh=your+message+here`

Comment: And in case I'd like to pass information differently? Let's say using the URL in order to pass a message doesn't suit it for me, is there any other ways to store information?

Comment: You can use `localStorage`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to user window.location.reload() you have to use Browser's sessionStorage. Here is my code, I use this for saving data.

```
window.onload = function () {

    var msg = sessionStorage.getItem("nameShah");

    if (msg == "Success") {

        sessionStorage.setItem("nameShah", "");

        alert("Saved Successfully");
    }
}

$("#save").click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/AspNetUsers/SaveData",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        data:{userName: "a"},
        success: function (data) {

            if (data.Msg == "Success") {

                sessionStorage.setItem("nameShah", "Success");
                window.location.reload();
            }         
        }
    });
});
```

Server Side:

```
    public ActionResult SaveData(string userName)
    {
        return Json(new { Msg = "Success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The way to go is using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('done refreshing and document is ready');
});
```

But it doesn't differentiate a first load from a refresh. But you could achive that using sessions. For example, using PHP:

```
<?php

session_start();

$showJs = false;

if( !isset($_SESSION['loaded_before']) ) {
    $showJs = true;
    $_SESSION['loaded_before'] = true;
}

?>
...
<?php if($showjs) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('done refreshing and document is ready');
    });

</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please check my response to xbonez's answer. I'd like to store some information using javascript/JQuery only, if possible.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to go javascript side, you can use sessionStorage.varName before reloading, and then you check that var and continue.